# How can I get rid of the label under a Google AppScript DatePicker widget

Tags: google-apps-script, datepicker

I have a Google AppScript card with a DatePicker widget:

```
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var section = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Receipt Data');
  var widget = CardService.newDatePicker().setFieldName('Date').setTitle('Date');
  widget.setValueInMsSinceEpoch(new Date().getTime());
  section.addWidget(widget);
  card.addSection(section);
```

It shows up like this, with the `.setTitle('Date')` string at the top, which is what I want to keep, and "Date" (which I circled in blue) below the widget's value, which I would liek to get rid of. Does anyone know how to get rid of that label?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Removing Label in Google Card Builder Services:

Unfortunately the input label that you are looking for to modify is a preset on the Card Builder you are using.

I would suggest using a web app instead for your desired design on your project. By doing this you can overcome the preset of the builder that you are using.

This is the code for removing the extra "Date" Input field to avoid redundancy of label should you choose to move forward with card builder.

If this options doesn't work for you I also suggest submit a feature idea on this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Try this:

### Code:

```
function buildCard() {
    let cardSection1DatePicker1 = CardService.newDatePicker()
        .setFieldName('date');

    let cardSection1 = CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(cardSection1DatePicker1);

    let card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setDisplayStyle(CardService.DisplayStyle.REPLACE)
        .addSection(cardSection1)
        .build();
    return card;
}
```

### Reference:

[Card Builder](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa2ZfVWxySDFfSTlfQTVmRkV6RV9uMFFKSjBYZ3xBQ3Jtc0trbTAxamJQNU1UQk8xMVcwbEJkSm1tZFVuOW1vREl5ajh2YTZDTWVWMGVjamJiRHRWUUxHcVp0VnB2OWZQajM4NWU0VXdEX0JjWmFmazdraS1IM1Y3RVJSZDZIeVc4c3g4aGJtLUszeFlldnBDTUpFbw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gle%2F3yf7mF0&v=3u6Kn8gje9I)

[Card Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service)